# List of --js-flags that can be used for Chrome on Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, v8

Does anyone have a good reference for all of the --js-flags="" that can be used in Chrome at the command line, for Windows?

For performance testing, I'm currently using: 
chrome.exe --no-sandbox --js-flags="--trace-deopt --trace-opt"

But, I'd like to know if there are other flags that will help illuminate a problem I'm having.

Specifically, other's have referenced --trace-bailout, but that one doesn't seem to work; it's unrecognized by Chrome; I'd love to see which functions aren't being optimized by Turbofan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V8 developer here. The authoritative list of V8 flags is the source: https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/src/flags/flag-definitions.h#188
When that file has, e.g., `DEFINE_BOOL(es_staging, ...)`, then the corresponding command-line syntax in Chrome would be `--js-flags="--es-staging"`.

> I'd love to see which functions aren't being optimized by Turbofan.

Turbofan optimizes all functions, assuming they run long enough. (Many years ago, there was a set of features that Crankshaft couldn't optimize; those days are long gone, Turbofan supports everything.)

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm trying to determine if there are in fact functions that are not being optimized. When using the flags:  "--trace-deopt --trace-opt"  is it safe to assume that if I see a log line that reads "completed optimizing... <JSFunction [name] ... using TurboFan" and there was not a DEOPT msg afterwards, that the function was ultimately optimized?  Conversely, if a function logs a DEOPT, but then does not log a "completed optimizing" message, is it correct to assume it was not optimized?

Comment: Yes. Deopt means that optimized code had to be thrown away (so it can only happen after optimization), such a function will be reoptimized later if it continues to run a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion. I had no idea there were so many options!

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
(Last automated update occurred on 2019-08-12.)

Comment: That's the list of Chrome flags, whereas the OP asked about V8 flags (which Chrome passes on via the `--js-flags="..."` switch).